# element.onclick returns null and element.getAttribute('onclick') does not

Tags: javascript

I thought that element.getAttribute('onclick') returns a string-version of whatever element.onclick is set to.

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i < as.length; i++) {
    // set test to some javascript text
    var test = as[i].getAttribute('onclick');

     // set test to "null"
    var test = String(as[i].onclick);
}
```

Why is the ".onclick" notation returning null, when the .getAttribute('onclick') shows a value?

Comment: Is it possible that other code on your program is detaching the `onclick` event? Also what is the `getAttribute` returning?

Comment: getAttribute('onclick') returns `"playSong({'title':'Orchids','artist':'Monster Rally','url' ... "});"` while String(as[i].onclick) returns "null". But when I try String(someFunction) in w3Schools' editor, I actually get the someFunction's body, in text form.

Answer (score 2):

```
.onclick
```

returns the function that is bound to the click event.

```
.getAttribute('onclick')
```

returns the string value of the attribute.

In plain HTML, if the code of the attribute is invalid, there is no click event defined and the first will return null.

In any case, the two will not return the same thing. The first returns a `function`, the second a `string`.

Comment: attached event handlers (via `addEventListener`) will not affect the `onclick` property or attribute.

Comment: So shouldn't the code String(as[i].onclick) return "function" and not "null" when the onclick handler is set?

Comment: @user2754009  Yes, it **does** return a function

Comment: No, I mean shouldn't String(as[i].onclick) return the **string** "function" or the text that defines that function? For example, the following code actually prints out "function () { document.write("some text"); }" when I try the code at w3schools, but something different is happening in my example which is running in chrome.
`<script>
var myfunction=function() { document.write("some text"); }

document.write(String(myfunction));

</script>`

Comment: It will return ***neither** the string *function* **nor** the *text* that defines the function. It returns the function itself !

Answer (score 1):

By `as[i].getAttribute('onclick')` you are getting value of attribute named "onclick" in element dom. It is used to get any existing attribute and not specific to `onclick`

and function `as[i].onclick` is used to define event, not to get any value.

Basic use of `onclick`:

```
as[i].onclick=function() {

   console.log('print when clicked');

};
```

Comment: in `as[i].onclick`, `onclick` is a property. Why do you think it's write-only? Reference please.

Comment: @JanDvorak I corrected it in answer. I written `as[i].onclick` instead of `as[i].getAttribute('onclick')`